# Neoload trying to create performance script to test sql server reponse.

Tags: sql-server, neoload

Trying to create Performance script in neoload to test sql server respone. Its the first time I am working on a scenario like this.

Added sql action provided by neoload. It has parameters - one of the parameters
says ConnectionURL - The JDBC Connection URL. Whats might be the format for establishing a connection to send request

Answer (score 0):

> **connectionURL:** jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Please go thro their website to get what you are looking for.. It has been clearly stated..

**Source link :** https://www.neotys.com/support/neotys-labs/sql

Once the connection has been established, the **SQL Statement Action** can be used to execute the queries. Once the queries have been implemented, pls do not forget to close the SQL connection with the **SQL disconnection** action!!